# If within a loop not working as expected java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I'm reading lines from a text file ("text.txt") and then storing them into a treemap, until the word apply appears.

However after performing this I don't have the last row "4 apply" I want in the treemap

text.txt
1 add
3 multiply
4 apply
6 add

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
while(input.hasNextLine()){

    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] divline = line.split(" ");

    TreeMap<Integer, String> Values = new TreeMap();

    if(!divline[1].equals("apply"))
    {
        Values.put(Integer.valueOf(divline[0]), divline[1]);    
    } 
    else
    {
        Values.put(Integer.valueOf(divline[0]), divline[1]);
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(Values);

}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop".

Comment: You can put `valores.put(Integer.valueOf(divline[0]), divline[1]);` outside de `ìf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new map inside while loop every time. Put below code before while loop.

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> valores = new TreeMap();
```

Also printing of map content needs to be corrected. So your final code can be

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
TreeMap<Integer, String> valores = new TreeMap();
     while(input.hasNextLine()){

        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] divline = line.split(" ");           

        if(!divline[1].equals("apply")){
            valores.put(Integer.valueOf(divline[0]), divline[1]);   
        } else {
            valores.put(Integer.valueOf(divline[0]), divline[1]);
            break;
        }             

    }

for (Entry<Integer,String> entry: valores){
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "- "+entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`4 apply` is getting added to `valores` map, but it's not getting printed because you are breaking out of the loop before the print statement.

Also, you may need to move the creation of `valores` map before `while` loop. And the printing after the loop.

```
    TreeMap<Integer, String> valores = new TreeMap();

    while(input.hasNextLine()){

    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] divline = line.split(" ");

    if(!divline[1].equals("apply")){
        valores.put(Integer.valueOf(divline[0]), divline[1]);   
    } else {
        valores.put(Integer.valueOf(divline[0]), divline[1]);
        break;
    }
    }

    System.out.println(valores);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new "valores" `TreeMap` for each line and then print that `TreeMap` that contains that one line. In the case of 'apply' you do the same, creating a new map, putting the value there - only by breaking, you skip the `System.out.println` part.

You need to put the declaration of the TreeMap before the while.